# Создание нового класса в ран-тайме через Boost::Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, рефлексия, runtime

Мне необходимо создать класс на лету каким-нибудь простым способом. Например через функцию модуля, которая будет возвращать новый класс.

Следующим способом создаётся класс для модуля, но к сожалению это нужно делать в строго указанном месте (через макрос `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`):

```
class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
    .def("my_method", &MyClass::my_method)
    .def("my_second_method", &MyClass::my_second_method);
```

Дело в том, что мне необходимо создавать на лету новые типы данных. В конкретно моём случае это типизированные массивы и фиксированные словари с типизированными значениями и неизменяемыми ключами. Это мне необходимо для того, чтобы оптимизировать существующий код: проблема оверхэда, так как в проекте используются данные передаваемые по сети в виде массивов, строгих диктов и вообще деревовидной структуры, по сей причине мне бы хотелось создавать классы фиксированных словарей на лету. То есть каждый новый класс будет содержать свой набор полей со своими типами, который будет имитировать `dict`, или же типизированный `list`, точнее это уже будет типизированный массив.

Выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
# объявлен тип данных подобный структуре C++
NewClass = DeclareFixedDictonary([('field_1', int32), ('field_2', String])

new_instance = NewClass(4, "Hi") 
new_instance['field_1'] = 6
new_instance['field_2'] = "qweqwe"

# ----------------------------------------------
NewArrayClass = DeclareTypedArray(NewClass)
new_array_instance = NewArrayClass([new_instance, NewClass()])

# ----------------------------------------------
NewComplexClass = DeclareFixedDictonary([('f1', float), ('f2', NewArrayClass), (f3, NewClass)])

# ... и тому подобное ...
```

В общем я решил, что смогу добиться максимальной производительности сделав эту фичу используя Boost::Python и Python API. Однако столкнулся с проблемой динамического создания классов или вообще объектов.

На данный же момент, следуя документации Boost::Python я могу делать что-то вроде:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(DataTypes)
{

    class_<DataTypesClass>("DataTypesClass")
        .def("set", &DataTypesClass::set)
        .def("get", &DataTypesClass::get)
        .def("set_item", &DataTypesClass::SetItem)
        .def("get_item", &DataTypesClass::GetItem)
        ;

}
```

То есть объявлять новые модульные классы. Однако мне ведь этого недостаточно. Наверняка у буста должен быть доступ к **рефлексии** питона. Или быть может мне использовать **генерацию кода** для таких случаев? Или просто я чего-то элементарного не вижу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните подробней проблему.

Comment: @Cerbo уточнил проблему в моём посте

Comment: вы хотите аналог `collections.namedtuple()` реализовать? Что конкретно работает медленно? Создайте [mcve] и результаты profiler покажите. Упомяните какая конкретно цель, например: операция X должна выполняться менее 1 секунды на вашем железе и используемых версиях софта.